# Adding and Loading objects from ASP.NET Session via Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a controller class like

```
class MyController : Controller
{
   User user
   {
       get
       {
         if(Session["User"] == null)
             Session["User"] = // Constructing object here
         return Session["User"];
       }
   }

   ....
}
```

I have lot of properties like User in this controller. I want to get/set without all this

```
if(Session["User"] == null)
```

noises. It could be something with attribute like

```
class MyController : Controller
{
   [SessionCacheObject("User")]
   User user;
}
```

How do I do this or is there any other smart way?

Comment: (Unrelated to what you are looking for) if you are using C# 6, this might be a good use of the `nameof` feature, in order to get rid of the 'magic strings'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my User session.

```
public static aspnet_Users LogInUser
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LogInUser"] != null)
                {
                    return (aspnet_Users)HttpContext.Current.Session["LogInUser"];
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["LogInUser"] = value;
            }

        }
```

Now, whenever add data to session like below.

```
LogInUser = user; // get data from wherever you need and set it.
```

Comment: This is almost similar to what I have written. I still want to abstract the if-else pattern appearing always for every property.

Comment: maybe it's possible but still it's not a good practice to add such type of code, because it dose not  make any sense to remove if-else, do you have any specific reason?